# Any group of order 2013 has a subgroup for each divisor of 2013

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> I want to prove that for any group of order $2013$ and any divisor of $2013$ there is some subgroup of that order.

$2013 = 11 \times3 \times61$ so we have a normal $11$-Sylow subgroup. Can someone hint how to proceed from here?

Comment: Your question is as in the title? I want to know `...how to proceed from here...`

Comment: yes, the question is to prove the title

Answer (score 2):

There are unique subgroups $\;P_{11}\,,\,P_{61}\;$ of order $\;11\,,\,61\;$ , resp. Thus the group $\;N:=P_{11}P_{61}\;$ is normal in $\;G\;$ , and then $\;G=P_3N\;$ , where $\;P_3\;$ is a subgroup of order three.

This means we have a semidirect product $\;G\cong N\rtimes P_3\;$, and this gives us two options: or the group is the cyclic one or the non-abelian semidirect product above. In each case we have , of course, a subgroup of each divisor.

Comment: quick question Antonio, what do you mean by "the cyclic one"? where is that coming from?

Comment: @masszz, By the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, there is only one abelian group of order $\;2013\;$ which, then, *must* be (the) a cyclic one.